# Hibernate Proxy Problem

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, lazy-loading

I'm sorry to ask such a basic question but I could not find a clear answer in others' questions:

I have a class `Foo`

```
public class Foo {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Bar bar;
  // getters and setters
}
```

And another class `Bar`

```
public class Bar {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Set<Foo> foos;

  // getters and setters 
}
```

I have a `ManagedBean` which has a `ManagedProperty` like this:

```
public class FooBean {
 @ManagedProperty(value = "{param.barId}"
 private Integer barId;
 private Bar bar;
 private Foo foo;

 public FooBean() {
 }

 @PostConstruct
 public void initialize() {
  SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();   
    if barId != null) {
      foo = new Foo();

      Session session = factory.openSession();

      try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        bar = (Bar) session.load(Bar.class, barId);        

        foo.setBar(bar);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
        if (tx.isActive()) {
          tx.rollback();
        }                
      } finally {
        session.close();
      }
    }
 }
}
```

And in my facelet I try to show the data thisway:

```
<h:outputText value="#{fooBean.foo.bar.name}" />
```

Which doesn't work! but If I add `bar.getName()` to my initialize method (after loading the bar) it works fine!
Why? And what is a best practice alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

```
lazy="false"
```

for the name property in your hibernate mapping xml.

Comment: I didn't know that basic classes like Integer and String properties can be lazy! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using

```
session.load(...)
```

This method assumes that the entity exist. So it does not have to query the database to check and can simply return a proxy that will load the entity later. If you call a Getter method of the `Bar` object you will initialize the proxy and you can make other calls later without database access.

If you use

```
session.get(...)
```

this should not happen, because Hibernate will get the entity from the database immediately to check if it exists and does not return a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do these:

- Use eager initialization in your schema (if you use annotations then use 'fetch = FetchType.EAGER'), this defines that everytime a Foo instance is retreived from the DB Foo.bar will be fetched.
- Write a jpa query which tells the API that foo.bar should be fetched in this query, something like this: 'From Foo foo join fetch foo.bar'

The first option is global, the second fetches the foo.bar for that query.